# NASM pass by reference

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I encountered a problem while coding in NASM (I am a beginner in this language). I am using pass by reference. The code should terminate when the value in [ebp-2](serve as counter) is equal to the value in [ebp+4](number from user). I am expecting 'checked' to be printed 5 times but the output is either an infinite loop or 'checked' printed n times.

This is a part of my code where the problem is happening:

```
find_prime:
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 2

        mov ecx, [ebp+4]      ;ecx contains address of ebp+4    
        mov word [ebp-2], 1   ;[ebp-2] as counter

        while1_begin:
            mov bx, [ebp-2]
            cmp bx, [ecx]     ;check if bx < [ecx]  
            je terminate      ;if bx = [ecx] terminate

            mov eax, 4
            mov ebx, 1
            mov ecx, pri      ;pri contains 'checked'
            mov edx, priLen
                int 80h

            inc word [ebp-2]
            jmp while1_begin

        while1_end:
            jmp terminate

        add esp, 2
        ret 4
```

Comment: `mov ecx, [ebp+4] ` moves the value at ebp+4 into ecx. If you want the address did you mean `lea ecx, [ebp+4]` ? Hard to tell since this isn't a minimal example. Your comment on that line is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: You say that this is pass by reference but your words and code seem to indicate that it's pass by value.

Comment: `add/sub esp,2` ... I would pad that to 4 at least (accessing word [ebp-2] is probably as good as word [ebp-4], I would just keep `esp` 4-byte boundary aligned). Although if it works now with `int 80h` using unaligned stack, then it's probably OK (or it hurts only performance).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code won't even assemble because where is **terminate**
2. Your algorithm is overly complicated as it could be structured like this.
3. Not that it is a requirement, but it is a good idea to preserve EBP

   ```
       push    ebp
       mov     ebp, esp
       mov     ecx, [ebp+8]

   L1: jcxz    done
       dec     ecx
       push    ecx
       .... Do printing here
       pop     ecx
       jmp     L1

   done:
       leave
       ret     4
   ```

NOTE: This example can even be compressed size wise if you know value passed will always be greater than zero, or at lease non-zero.
Otherwise, the only real problem was not preserving ECX in loop.

Comment: *Your code won't even assemble because where is terminate* what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @FUZxxl There is a conditional and absolute jmp to a place called `terminate`. Where is the label `terminate:`.

Comment: The OP wrote in his question _This is a **part** of my code_

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes OP did, but I don't think, based on code structure, it was unreasonable to think `terminate` does not exist, so the comment was intended to draw attention to what is probably an error.